# if statement with img.src

Tags: javascript

The problem: whenever, if i have the single '=' the variable will show up and be fine.. but it completely ignores the if statement.  if i only do the double '=='.. the variable doesnt show up, and it goes to the else state.  lemme know if u see anything wrong.

```
var pic1 = document.getElementById('team1pic').src;
var win1 = document.getElementById('wins').innerHTML;
if (pic1 == 'pens.jpg') {
    document.getElementById('wins').innerHTML = PittWins;
} else {
    document.getElementById('wins').innerHTML = 'no';
}
```

here is some html to go along with it that i have

```
<a class="dock-item" id="pens" href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('team1pic').src='pens.jpg'"><span>Pittsburgh Penguins</span><img src="pens.jpg" alt="Pittsburgh Penguins" /></a>`
```

and then

```
<th width="35%" ><img src="" / id='team1pic'></th>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be nice to see the HTML this is attached to.

The reason the single `=` works but `==` doesn't points to the conclusion that they are not equal. The reason it shows up for `=` is because the assignment evaluates to true. This will be the case for anything you assign to the variable that is "truthy", meaning the value would evaluate true in JS. In javascript everything but `0`, `false`, `null` & `undefined` evaluate to true.

You might want to do an `alert(pic1)` to see just what is in there, or if you are using Firefox or Chrome you can use the Javascript debugger tools.

Comment: the alert for pic1 gives off the document url for some reason?  i have team1pic set to change onclick .. so it's not defined until that click

Answer (score 2):

Do an `alert(pic1)` before the `if` and you'll figure it out.

The only "problem" is that `pic1` is not equal to `'pens.jpg'`. If you replace with a single `=`, the assignment operator, you get an expression that evaluates to `'pens.jpg'`, which is always `true`, so it always runs the first branch.

Answer (score 1):

Better:

```
var s = document.getElementById('team1pic').src,
    w = document.getElementById('wins');

w.innerHTML = s == 'pens.jpg' ? PittWins : 'no';
```

I assume that `PittWins` is a variable.

Comment: i am now getting some results.. i have document.getElementById('team1pic').src set to change onclick to different images.  the images are showing up in the right spots.. but it's still not giving the results. i updates answer with more code

Answer (score 1):

use

```
var pic1 = document.getElementById('team1pic').getAttribute('src',2);
```

...to get the src like it's defined and not the complete path.

Comment: still no go although it seems like it that would do the trick.  should i set if statement to the full name path.  an interesting thing i'm learning is that the 'no' (else statement) is coming up before the onclick even happen.  is there a better way to do ifs and onclicks together?

Comment: What is PittWins? Is it a variable?